# Logstash grok filter custom date

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

Im working on writing a logstash grok filter for syslog messages coming from my Synology box. An example message looks like this.

```
Jun  3 09:39:29 diskstation Connection user:\tUser [user] logged in from [192.168.1.121] via [DSM].
```

Im having a hard time filtering out the weirdly formatted timestamp. Could anyone give me a helping hand here? This is what I have so far.

```
if [type] == "syslog" and [message] =~ "diskstation" {
    grok {
      match => [ "message", "%{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{WORD:program} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" ]
    }
  }
```

As you can probably tell I havent dealt with the timestamp yet at all. Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following config can help you to parse the log.

```
grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:date} %{HOSTNAME:hostname} %{WORD:program} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" ]
}
```

You can try your log and pattern at [here](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) and refer all the provided pattern at [here](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns).

Comment: Those links will surely be of tremendous help! Thank you!